# SetApprovalForAll for multiple contracts in 1 txid

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I was wondering if it was possible to set approval for multiple collections in 1 txid, rather then approving each collection individually.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The problem is that one transaction has just one initial target.

The initial target can be a contract, which can call multiple more targets, but then the `msg.sender` changes and the sender of those subsequent calls is not you anymore. So, while retaining you as the `msg.sender`, you can only reach one target. Therefore, you can only send one `setApprovalForAll`.

One solution would be to use a smart contract to handle the assets. Or, even better - a smart contract wallet which is meant for this kind of stuff.